# Problems installing nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I had nodemon installed previously and it worked all of a sudden when try to use it i get an error, so i uninstall the previously installed nodemo and i cant install another anymore, below is the output i get

```
C:\Users\USER>npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...nwsFcBAEBCAAQBQJbRILi'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-10T22_53_48_120Z-debug.log
```

Comment: don't use the `-g` flag, try to install `npm install nodemon`!

Comment: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1029

Comment: Install locally and run like

`"scripts": {
   "serve": "nodemon server.js" //server.js being my launch file
   }`

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: i want to use install nodemon globally, am not in the capacity to install locally in every project i make